# when does clojure.core.typed/cf in core.typed evaluate and infer the type

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.typed

I don't quite understand the behavior or `clojure.core.typed/cf` as explained below.

I assume `cf` is used to infer the type of a form

```
(t/cf (+ 1 2)) => Long
```

Now, this fails

```
(t/cf (/ 1 0)) => Error
```

This indicates to me that the sexpr was evaluated prior to be type checked. I had expected `Long`.

When I define a custom function:

```
(t/ann my-fn [t/Any -> t/Num])
(defn my-fn [x]
  (assert (number? x))
  (println "CALLED")
  x)
```

I can used this in the same expression again and it fails, indicating that the fn was indeed called.

```
(t/cf (/ 1 (my-fn 0)) => Error, because it evaluates my-fn. no type inference here??
```

However, then the following makes no sense to me.

```
(t/cf (range)) => (t/ASeq t/AnyInteger)
```

Why is in this case function range NOT evaluated, also if it did evaluate the expression, the following examples should return the same type:

```
(t/cf (->> (range 2) vec)) =>  (t/AVec (t/U Short Byte Integer BigInteger Long BigInt))
(t/cf [0 1]) =>  [(t/HVec [(t/Val 0) (t/Val 1)]) {:then tt, :else ff}]
```

But they return different types.

My gut feeling is that it has to do with *constants*, i.e. when I type check a form that contains t/Val's, then core.typed autoamtically evaluates it. This however doesn't explain why for certain functions it does not evaluate it. The `2` in `(range 2)` is definitely a constant, so why this difference in behavior.

If the forms are evaluated before type checking then the following should have the same behavior

```
(t/cf (map inc (range 10))))
(t/cf (map #(inc %) (range 10))))
```

But `core.typed` does indeed see a difference. The second example fails because the anonymous `fn` receives a `t/Any` by default and you cannot call `inc` on it. So this means that `core.typed` must do some analysis of the form plus it also evaluates it. I find this a bit confusing I confess, maybe someone can enlighten me.

Edit: A short summary

Why does the following relation seems to be true in some but not all cases?

```
(t/cf form) <=> (let [x form] (t/cf x))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`core.typed` performs completely static type checking.

The compilation pipleline for `cf` is `read -> analyze -> type check -> eval`.

If there is a static type error, that is considered fatal.

Otherwise the evaluation will be performed.

`(cf (/ 1 0))` throws a runtime error because `(/ 1 0)` is a well-typed expression.

The *reason* evaluation is needed is related to the practicalities of analysing Clojure code — strange things happen if you analyze code then don’t evaluate it.